# Best configuration and deployment strategies for Rails on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting ready to deploy an application, and I'd like to make sure I'm using the latest and greatest tools.

The plan is to host on EC2, as Heroku will be cost prohibitive for this application. In the recent past, I used Chef and the Opscode platform for building and managing the server infrastructure, then Capistrano for deploying.

Is this still considered a best (or at least "good") practice? The Chef setup is great once done, but pretty laborious to set up. Likewise, Capistrano has been good to me over the past several years, but I thought I'd take some time to look around and seeing if there's been any landscape shifts that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano is still the norm best i can tell. I recently setup our apps on ec2 via chef-server. I came across a little known chef resource called deploy, I think, that is based on Capistrano, but let's you "bake" deploying right into your recipes. It supports pretty much the same things as Capistrano does. We are still deploying via Capistrano currently due to a tight deployment deadline, but my team wants me to investigate it further and try it out in staging. I'm really hoping to get it working and try to move to continuous deployments. http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Deploy+Resource